About a show started or produced by Isaac Asimov
Isaac Asimov started or produced a show about a genius who owned a warehouse full of stuff and experiments and he with an assistant (who was assigned to watch him) solved a number of unusual crimes that had some ingenious scientific basis. It didn't last long; was there a final episode or was it just cut off?

Are you asking for the name of this show or do you already know it? In the former case, is that your actual question? In the latter case, adding the name into the question might help tremendously with answering it.

Sounds similar to Probe
Was a 2-hour pilot and six episodes.

The pilot and series starred Parker Stevenson as Austin James, a misanthropic genius who solved high tech crimes, and Ashley Crow as James' new secretary Mickey Castle.

And the main character sounds like what you're describing:

Austin James (played by Parker Stevenson): A genius-level scientist and inventor with eidetic memory, Austin is constantly thinking, inventing ground-breaking technology and seeking answers to various mysteries and problems. [...] Austin is occasionally called in by local police to investigate baffling homicides, though he professes to not understand the motivation for murder. He founded the think tank Serendip, but he has no interest in managing its day-to-day affairs, preferring to spend most of his time engaged in a variety of experiments and investigations at his "workshop," a refurbished warehouse which serves as his home and laboratory.

It was co-written by Isaac Asimov and William Link.

Some information on "Probe" is here: http://www.tv.com/shows/probe/  (but very little)

Did anybody say why it was cancelled ; was it the usual excuse ,' poor ratings'?

@201044 I couldn't find anything that says why.  It looks like it was a mid-season pickup, taking over the spot of another show, so I would guess it wasn't well advertised and probably set up to fail.

If enough fans ask for it has fan support ever restarted a previously cancelled show ( other than Star Trek)?

@201044 Probably not after this much time has passed... They remade Battlestar Galactica but I don't think that's the same thing.  Arrested Development is the show most people mention when talking about fans bringing a show back from the dead but here's a list of seven: http://mentalfloss.com/article/32093/7-television-shows-saved-their-fans  It is not an exhaustive list.

I remember one 'Probe' episode was about someone using a designer virus to murder someone and quite recently in the show Limitless some executive used a designer virus targeting men who were related to Ghangus Khan ( forgive spelling). So even brilliant shows can borrow ideas..


Asimov did none of the writing. The chief writer was Michael Wagner. 2. "Probe" was placed opposite the "Bill Cosby Show". 3. After the pilot and the six episodes were aired, there came a prolonged writers' strike, during which "Probe" died.

